# Why is this not printing in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I try to print some simple ascII art but none of of it shows up, what am I doing wrong? I would think this would work because the person has to input something to continue in the first place.
All I am trying to do is make a simple game of rock, paper scissors. Also i am on python 3.9.4 if that has anything to do with it.

```
import random
import time
import ctypes
import os


def Main_Game():
    y = input("Enter choice: ")
    b = random.choice(choices)
    # both put same; draw
    if y == b:
        print("Game ended with a draw!")
        print("Player chose = " + y + "| Bot chose = " + b)
    # player puts rock and bot puts paper; bot wins
    elif y == "rock" and b == "paper":
        print("Bot won the match with paper!")
        print("Player chose = " + y + "| Bot chose = " + b)
    # player puts paper and bot puts rock; player wins
    elif y == "paper" and b == "rock":
        print("Player won the match with paper!")
        print("Player chose = " + y + "  |  Bot chose = " + b)
    # player puts paper and bot puts scissors; bot wins
    elif y == "paper" and b == "scissors":
        print("Bot won the match with scissors!")
        print("Player chose = " + y + "  |  Bot chose = " + b)
    # player puts scissors and bot puts paper; player wins
    elif y == "scissors" and b == "paper":
        print("Player won the match with scissors!")
        print("Player chose = " + y + "  |  Bot chose = " + b)
    # player puts rock and bot puts scissors; player wins
    elif y == "rock" and b == "scissors":
        print("Player won the match with rock!")
        print("Player chose = " + y + "  |  Bot chose = " + b)
    # player puts scissors and bot puts rock; bot wins
    elif y == "scissors" and b == "rock":
        print("Bot won the match with rock!")
        print("Player chose = " + y + "  |  Bot chose = " + b)
    elif y == 'rock':
        print("""
            _______
        ---'   ____)
              (_____)
              (_____)
              (____)
        ---.__(___)
        """)
        print("""
              #     #   #####  
              #     #  #     # 
              #     #  #       
              #     #   #####  
              #   #         # 
              # #    #     # 
              #      #####  
        """)
    elif y == 'paper':
        print("""
             _______
        ---'    ____)____
                   ______)
                  _______)
                 _______)
        ---.__________)
        """)
        print("""
              #     #   #####  
              #     #  #     # 
              #     #  #       
              #     #   #####  
              #   #         # 
              # #    #     # 
              #      #####  
        """)
    elif y == 'scissors':
        print("""
            _______
        ---'   ____)____
                  ______)
               __________)
              (____)
        ---.__(___)
        """)
        print("""
              #     #   #####  
              #     #  #     # 
              #     #  #       
              #     #   #####  
              #   #         # 
              # #    #     # 
              #      #####  
        """)
    time.sleep(3)
    clear()
    Main_Game()


clear = lambda: os.system("cls")
choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW("Playing rock, paper, scissors!")
Main_Game()
```

Comment: Probably because `y` has a `\n` appended to the end of it, so it doesn't match any of your choices.  Try `print(repr(y))` to see what's really there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`elif` only checks its condition if the previous branches were all false, and your branches handle every possible input. You probably meant for the `elif y ==  'rock'` line to be `if y == 'rock'`, so we check the condition no matter the values of the previous conditions.

Answer (score 3):

Silvio's answer solves your immediate problem, but I thought I'd post some suggestions on how to clean up this code a bit.

First off, the ascii art data makes the logic a bit hard to read, I would move these to some const values at the start of the script:

```
ROCK_ART = """
    _______
---'   ____)
      (_____)
      (_____)
      (____)
---.__(___)
"""
PAPER_ART = """
    _______
---'    ____)____
           ______)
          _______)
         _______)
---.__________)
"""
SCISSORS_ART = """
    _______
---'   ____)____
          ______)
       __________)
      (____)
---.__(___)
"""
VS_ART = """
#     #   #####  
#     #  #     # 
#     #  #       
#     #   #####  
#   #         # 
# #    #     # 
#      #####  
"""
```

You can define a dictionary for easy lookup of these images.

```
ART = {
    "rock": ROCK_ART,
    "paper": PAPER_ART,
    "scissors": SCISSORS_ART,
    "vs": VS_ART,
}
```

Now there's a lot of repeated logic in checking who wins. Imagine if you wanted to program  to play ["Rock paper scissors lizard spock"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Rock_paper_scissors_lizard_spock.png). Thats a whole lot of choices to check and values to hard code. What if instead we put these rules into a dictionary.

```
MATCH_UPS = {
    "rock": "scissors",
    "paper": "rock",
    "scissors": "paper",
}
```

To see who wins a fight you could do `if MATCH_UPS[y] == b` to see if the user wins. On that note, use more descriptive names for variables or things will get confusing for you fast.

Putting this altogether:

```
def main_game():
    user_choice = input("Enter choice: ")
    bot_choice = random.choice(list(MATCH_UPS.keys()))

    print(ART[user_choice])
    print(ART["vs"])
    print(ART[bot_choice])
    print(f"Player chose = {user_choice} | Bot chose = {bot_choice}")

    if user_choice == bot_choice:
        print("Game ended with a draw!")
    elif MATCH_UPS[user_choice] == bot_choice:
        print(f"Player won the match with {user_choice}!")
    else:
        print(f"Bot won the match with {bot_choice}!")

    time.sleep(3)
    os.system("cls")
    main_game()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_game()
```

Comment: Man thanks I will be sure to do this for future projects.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to draw the flow diagram of your game.
In your code when a player enters a choice, you generate a random choice from the bot and compare it using if and elif, but when a statement matches let's say
`elif y == 'rock' and b == 'scissors':` then the flow would stop as the code only goes through elif statements if the previous ones didn't match
so you should change your code by breaking this part

```py
  elif y == "scissors" and b == "rock":
        print("Bot won the match with rock!")
        print("Player chose = " + y + "  |  Bot chose = " + b)
  if y == 'rock':
```

so that it executes the ASCII print statements as well

Answer (score 1):

It is not

```
elif y=='rock':
```

change it to

```
if y=='rock':
```

because you want to print the ascii art for the players input, and it does not depend on the system's choice.